# Extract Specific Number in between symbols in a long string

Tags: python, regex

I have a long string captured from a log txt file which have sequence as below:

526136|20190403164654|**3**|06010003530075508541|1|8801851088890|

Is there any method to capture the 3rd field, which is the "3" value from each line using regex? I am aware that i can use the findall function to search for all number values and then capture the 3rd element in the list. Is there any other methods that is more efficient and simpler in coding?
Thanks all

Comment: What is the point of capturing? Isn't it enough to confirm that the string contains the substring of interest?

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
text = "526136|20190403164654|3|06010003530075508541|1|8801851088890"

pattern = r"\|\d\|"
new_text = re.search(pattern,text)
print(new_text)

#or

new_text = text.split("|")
print(new_text[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
>>> a = """1|2|3|4|5|
... 6|7|8|9|10|
... 11|12|13|14|15|
... 16|17|18|19|20|"""
>>> re.findall(r'^.*?\|.*?\|([\d]*?)\|', a, 10)
['3', '8', '13', '18']
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re
ptrn = re.compile(r"\|")
s = "526136|20190403164654|3|06010003530075508541|1|8801851088890|"
number = re.split(ptrn, s)[2]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regex for this, you can just `.split()` and find the Nth element!

```py
>>> s = "526136|20190403164654|3|06010003530075508541|1|8801851088890|"
>>> s.split("|")[2]
'3'
```